# using This for input options if selected value then do this

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use this in my jquery so that i can use the same class but have the effect independent of each other

heres the fiddle I'm working on

http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/ThnKc/

as you can when you select option 3 the word HEY comes out for both select tags but i want it to be independent of each other using the same class.

I think i Can do this using something like

```
 $(this).children('div.custom_size').fadeIn()
```

but it does not seem to work and I've been stuck and frustrated for a long time

heres the html

```
 <select id="print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite">
   <option value="">1</option>
   <option value="">2</option>
   <option value="customSize">3</option>
 </select>

 <div class="custom_size" style="display: none;">
   Hello
 </div>

 <br />
 <br />
 <br />
 <select id="print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite">
   <option value="">1</option>
   <option value="">2</option>
   <option value="customSize">3</option>
 </select>

 <div class="custom_size" style="display: none;">
   Hello
 </div>
```

heres the Jquery

```
  $("#print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite").change(function(evt) {
    var selected;
    selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected === "customSize") {
      return $(".custom_size").fadeIn();
  } else {
     return $(".custom_size").fadeOut();
  }
   }).change();
```

I'm super new to jQuery so if you can show me in the fiddle that would be great!

thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this will help. id i think should be unique for element

http://jsfiddle.net/sUuqd/1/

```
$(".print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite").change(function(evt) {
 var selected;
 selected = $(this).val();
 if (selected === "customSize") {
    return $(this).parent().find(".custom_size").fadeIn();
  } else {
return $(this).parent().find(".custom_size").fadeOut();
 }
}).change();
```

Comment: No, an `id` 'should' not be unique, it ***must*** be unique within the document.

Answer (score 0):

Supply a context relative to the `$(this)` element:

```
  if (selected === "customSize") {
    return $(this).next(".custom_size").fadeIn();
  } else {
    return $(this).next(".custom_size").fadeOut();
  }
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ThnKc/7/).

*Also* you have invalid HTML, an `id` ***must be unique within the document***, therefore you should be using a class-name for your `select` elements instead:

```
<select class="print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite">
<!-- removed for brevity -->
</select>
<div class="custom_size" style="display: none;">Hello</div>
<!-- removed for brevity -->
<select class="print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite">
<!-- removed for brevity -->
</select>
<div class="custom_size" style="display: none;">Hello</div>
```

With the jQuery:

```
$(".print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite").change(function (evt) {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $(this).next('.custom_size')[selected === 'customSize' ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut']();
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ThnKc/9/).

And, finally, because sometimes I just like to use ternary operators a little too much:

```
$(".print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite").change(function (evt) {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $(this).next('.custom_size')[selected === 'customSize' ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut']();
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ThnKc/8/).

Comment: the other input tag does not seem to work with that code only the top one displays 'hey'

Comment: Yes, that's because you had *two* elements sharing an `id` which is invalid. See the edit I was making as you commented.

Comment: @user1502223 look at my answer and especially the fiddle. that demonstrates what you are looking for. also notice that i changed the selector from an id to "select"

Answer (score 0):

Look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fge7S/). I added a `for="someid"` attribute to the select and us that attribute to identify which div the select stands for.

my js looks like this:

```
$("select").change(function(evt) {
  var selected;
  selected = $(this).val();
  if (selected === "customSize") {
    return $(".custom_size#"+$(this).attr("for")).fadeIn();
  } else {
    return $(".custom_size#"+$(this).attr("for")).fadeOut();
  }
}).change();
```

and the html like that:

```
<select id="print_size_options_LargeFormatBlackWhite" for="a">
   <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="">2</option>
    <option value="customSize">3</option>
</select>

<div id="a" class="custom_size" style="display: none;">
    Hello
</div>
```

the second select just has a `for="b"` and the second div has `id="b"`

Comment: The `for` attribute is not valid for a `select` element, it's only valid for a `label` element (to associate a `label` with an `input` (or `select` or `textarea`) element. If you must use a custom attribute, use a `data-*` attribute, then at least it's valid (under HTML 5).

Comment: Well, yes. My point wasn't that `data-*` was the *only* option, but if you're going to use a non-standard element, I'd advise not using an attribute that's specifically invalid for that element (regardless of what other attribute you choose, instead, to use).